# Closed subsets of compact sets in metric space are compact-clarification on proof

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am writing the proof of title statement as is given in the textbook, followed by doubts on the proof:

" Let X be a metric space and K be a compact set in X.  Suppose F is a closed subset of K. Since K is compact, it is closed in X. Since F is closed in K, it is closed in X. Let {V$_\alpha$} be an open cover of F. If F$^c$ is adjoined to {V$_\alpha$}, we obtain an open cover $\Omega$ of K. Since K is compact, there is a finite subcollection $\Phi$ of $\Omega$ which covers K, hence F. If F$^c$ is a member of $\Phi$ we may remove it from $\Phi$ and still retain an open cover of F. We have thus shown that a finite subcollection of {V$_\alpha$} covers F. Therefore F is compact"

My doubts are:

1. Is not F$^c$ always a member of $\Phi$? When can it be not a member?
2. The moment we say K is compact and therefore has a finite subcollection $\Phi$ of $\Omega$ which covers K and hence F, should not the proof end here? I have not understood why F$^c$ needs to be removed from $\Phi$

Would be grateful for guidance on above matter

Comment: The crucial point is that you know the following: For each open cover *of K* there is an finite subcover that covers K. But your proof starts with an open cover *of F*. So you have to extend it to an open cover of K in order to proceed.

Comment: We need a finite subset  of $\{V_a\}$ that covers$ F$, and $F^c$ may fail to be a member of $\{V_a\}.$ So we must remove $F^c$ from  $\Phi$ when $F^c\not \in \Phi.$ For example when $\{V_a\}$  covers all of $X$ and $F^c\not \in \{V_a\}$.  However  we can safely remove it in all cases.... And I dk why the author didn't write $V$ instead of $\{V_a\}$.

Comment: Note that this proof works on any topological space.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, for you, an open cover of $F$ is a set $\{V_\alpha\}$ of open subsets of $X$ whose union contains $F$. In this case, no, $F^c$ does not have to be contained in $\Phi$. There are many easy examples. For starters, you might think about the case where the covering $\{V_\alpha\}$ is $\{X\}$.

For 2.: We want to show that $F$ is compact, that is, for every open cover $\{V_\alpha\}$ of $F$ we want to find a finite subcollection of $\{V_\alpha\}$ which is still covering $F$. We cannot stop before we have found this subcollection. So after having obtained a finite subcollection $\Phi$ of $\Omega$ which covers $K$ we have to remove $F^c$ to obtain a finite subcollection of $\{V_\alpha\}$. Using the property of $\Phi$ covering $K$, one concludes that the corresponding finite subcollection of $\{V_\alpha\}$ covers $F$ and only then you are done.

Comment: Thank you...that does make it clear